# When Should I Use @JoinColumn or @JoinTable with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

`@JoinColumn` gives an `Entity` a foreign key to another `Entity` whereas `@JoinTable` will list the relationship between all relationships between `Entity` A and `Entity` B.  As far as I can tell, they both appear to do similar things. When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let's say you have an entity `A` which has a `@ManyToOne` association ot an entity `B`

[@JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) will define the target table Foreign Key (e.g `B_ID`) while using the target Entity table (e.g. `B`).

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    private B b;

}
```

[@JoinTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) will use a separate table to hold the relationship between `A` and `B`.

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
       name = "A_B", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    )
    private B b;

}
```

This time neither `A` nor `B` contain any Foreign Key, because there's a separate table (e.g. `A_B`) to hold the association between `A` and `B`.

Comment: so a JoinTable is a N-N relationship ?

Comment: In database terminology, it's a many-to-many association. In this case, one FK will have a unique constraint to turn it into a one-to-many association with a join table.

Answer (score 24):

@JoinTable stores the id of both the table into a separate table while @JoinColumn stores id of the another table in a new column.

@JoinTable : This is the default type. Use this when you you need a more normalized database. ie. to reduce redundancy.

@JoinColumn : Use this for better performance as it does not need to join extra table.

Answer (score 5):

**one important difference**: `@JoinColumn` always  [depends upon the context](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) it is used:

> - If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign    key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the
>     source entity or embeddable.
> - If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign    key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of
>     the target    entity.
> - If the join is for a ManyToMany mapping or for a OneToOne or    bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany mapping using a join table, the
>     foreign key is in a join table.
> - If the join is for an element collection, the foreign key is in a    collection table.